# I am trying to display a float value on an lcd , for the same I have to first convert it to a string.But it just doesn't work

Tags: c, embedded

`weather.outdooe_temp` is a `float` value which is being updated every time I press a button. `set_temp` is a `float` to `ascii` function. If I use that the thing works, but not if I use the code below.

```
char Thermo_Buff66[4];
static void SetBox(ScreenObj_t const *pS, EVENT_MSG const *pMsg)
{
    //set_temp(weather.outdoor_temp,&a);//it works if i use this function.
    sprintf(Thermo_Buff66,"%2.1f",weather.outdoor_temp);
    (void)sprintf(Thermo_Buff,"%s\xc2\xb0""",Thermo_Buff66);
    (void)DataBoxHandler(pS, &msg, "Set Temp", (uint8_t *)Thermo_Buff);

    //currently displaying any # value....!!ing!!
 }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. Why is there both `Thermo_Buff` and `Thermo_Buff66`? How are we supposed to know how `set_temp()` works, it doesn't even get a string buffer sent to it?

Comment: Ok let me simplify it: If I send the float value to a ftoa function it works but if I use sprintf(Thermo_Buff66,"%2.1f",weather.outdoor_temp);     It displays # values.

Comment: I just tried if it would probably work this way. Just a trial an error but didn't really work. set_temp is a float to ascii converter fucntion. @unwind

Comment: Your `Thermo_Buff66` array isn't very big, and the format you have used doesn't make a lot of sense - you want it to be 2 characters wide, including the '.' - likely your actual number will end up wider than that...

Comment: Initially i did that to just cancel out the unessential part. But ya i put Thermo_Buff66[50]. Still the same problem @JasonD

Comment: Can you clarify what this sentence means: "currently displaying any # value....!!ing!!"

Comment: I was wondering if the `sprintf()` implementation sees that the number is too long for the specified format and replaces it with '#' characters...

Comment: #value = any garbage value@Shahbaz.......ya probably @JasonD

Answer (score 1):

```
char Thermo_Buff66[4];
sprintf(Thermo_Buff66,"%2.1f",weather.outdoor_temp);
```

The buffer you have allocated (`Thermo_Buff66`) is too short for a floating number representing outdoor temperature (often 2 digits) plus a `.` plus a digit after. Indeed, it doesn't have space for the terminating `'\0'` character. So immediate correction would be to set the size to `5`. Still, in case of armageddon (or simply being in a non-SI country ... cough ... US), the temperature could even get to above 100, in which case again you overflow your buffer. Do yourself a favor and use `snprintf`.

Regardless, you `sprintf` into a buffer, then using `%s` you `sprintf` it into something else, which there is no point to. You can do it all directly in one, removing `Thermo_Buff66` altogether:

```
(void)sprintf(Thermo_Buff, "%.1f\xc2\xb0", weather.outdoor_temp);
(void)DataBoxHandler(pS, &msg, "Set Temp", (uint8_t *)Thermo_Buff);
```

Side note: the `.` and the precision digit already take up 2 characters. Setting minimum width to 2 is therefore reduntant. Perhaps you thought the 2 in `%2.1` is the number of digits before the `.`? Well it's not. It's the minimum *overall* width.